# Copy files of certain extension from subdirectories and place them in new subdirectories of same structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going through a list of computers and searching a certain directory and subdirs for anything with a file extension of .exe.config

I want to take those files ending in .exe.config and place them in a backup directory of the same structure.  So this would be done recursively.

For example, "main" is the main directory.  There are several subdirs within "main" called "1", "2", "3", etc

```
main
\
 \-----------
 \   \    \
 1   2    3
```

In each of the numbered directories, there would be a file with the extension of .exe.config

I want to grab the main directory name, sub directory names, and *.exe.config files. Then place them in a backup "main" directory with the same structure.

There are other files in those numbered directories but I want to ignore those.

I'm not able to copy everything recursively.  Here is the code I have been testing.  A list of computers is placed in the serverlist.txt

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput

def copy_names(servername):

    source = r'//' + servername + '/c$/Program Files (x86)/Main/'
    dest = r'//' + servername + '/c$/' + servername + '/Main/'

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.exe.config'):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
                    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))
                    print ("\n" + servername + " " + file + " : Copy Complete")
                except:
                    print (" Directory you are copying to does not exist.")

def start():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    array = []
    with open("serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
        for servername in f:
            copy_names(servername.strip())


# start program
start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with these changes?

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput

def copy_names(servername):

    source = r'//' + servername + '/c$/Program Files (x86)/Main/'
    dest = r'//' + servername + '/c$/' + servername + '/Main/'

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.exe.config'):
                file_src = os.path.join(root, file)
                file_dest = file_src.replace('Program Files (x86)', servername)
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_dest), exist_ok=True)
                try:
                    shutil.copyfile(file_src, file_dest)
                    print ("\n" + servername + " " + file + " : Copy Complete")
                except:
                    print (" Directory you are copying to does not exist.")

def start():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    array = []
    with open("serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
        for servername in f:
            copy_names(servername.strip())


# start program
start()
```

`os.path.join(source, file)` does not give you the correct location of the source file; you should use something like `os.path.join(root, file)` instead.

There's probably a more robust way to get `file_dest` than `file_dest = file_src.replace('Program Files (x86)', servername)`, but I can't think of it ATM.